# Ansible Using large variable in playbook opts to fail while pasting the raw data in, or using other smaller variables will run

Tags: ansible, jinja2, uri

I want to push ios_facts to gitlab using ansibles uri module.

```
- name: get ios facts
  ios_facts:
    gather_subset: all
  register: ios_facts

- name: commit to gitlab
  delegate_to: localhost
  uri:
    url: http://gitlab/api/v4/projects/2/repository/commits
    method: POST
    body_format: json
    status_code: 201
    headers:
      PRIVATE-TOKEN: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
    body: |
      {
        "branch": "master",
        "commit_message": "{{ ansible_net_hostname }} update",
        "actions": [
         {
           "action": "update",
           "file_path": "conf/{{ ansible_net_hostname }}",
           "content": "{{ ansible_net_config }}"
         }
        ]
      }
```

The Playbook works fine if I am using any **other variable than ansible_net_config**, or if I am **pasting the raw content of ansible_net_config** instead of using the jinja2 reference. The ansible_net_config is a large string using \n as new line and contains some special characters. I guess the problem occurs because I don't get valid json when the playbook parses.

I then get the HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Is there any filter I can apply or any other thing I might be missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue:
The API Call failed when the variable contains "\n". I could make it work by replacing "\n" with escaped "\\n":

```
...
"content": {{ ansible_net_config | replace('\n','\\n') }}
...
```